# Macro for random 20% of cases from a report

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet which has data of around 10,000 cases and I need to select 20% random cases from it. The sheet name is called "case review" and the data needs to be added onto a tab called "case allocation". The cases have to be picked at random and display all the data from that row into the case allocation tab. Can Someone please help me with a macro for this. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried with your code?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a tiny trick that involves no programming at all !

Say the original data is in columns **A** through **Z** with row#1 being the header row.

In col **AA**, cell **AA2** enter:

```
=RAND()
```

and copy down as far as you have data in the other rows.  Then copy column **AA** and *PasteSpecialValues* back onto itself.  Then *AutoFilter* column **AA** for values less than or equal to ***.2***.

This will select about 20% of the original rows at random. If you need *exactly* 20%, then increase the .2 limit and pick up only those rows needed to satisfy 20%.

Copy the visible rows and paste to the other worksheet. *(or write a macro to do the copy/paste for you)*.

Comment: I tried to test it, because i thought it a nice trick =]. But i think i am making something wrong. Because my Rand() numbers just range from 0 to 1, but i pasted special and used filter for `<= 0.2`. And the result: from 1104 cells, it got 226, the expected value was 220,8. Acceptable error, maybe it needs more values to become more accurate

Comment: @danieltakeshi  **You are correct**  An improvement would be to filter for less than or equal to .22 and then discard the excess.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I could do this however, as this task will be distributed between a team to do, they are not excel literate, therefore a macro option would be the only option for ease of use amongst the team. The data should be extracted from cell A4, copying columns A to H and this will need to be pasted in cell A2 on the case allocation tab.